# Putting the mean of a binary variable column in a new data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to make a new data frame that contains the mean of a binary variable. For instance, I have:

| Win | Average |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0.66 |
| 0 | 0.5 |
| 0 | 0.4 |
| 1 | 0.5 |
| 0 | .42 |

On the "Win" category, I have some 500 entries. I am looking to build a new column like "Average" that calculates the average of the entry in the "Win" column up to that point -- not the average of the "Win" category completely. So an entry in row number 56 will calculate the average Win Rate from column 1 to 56 and populate it in the corresponding row.

Comment: `transform(data, Average = dplyr::cummean(Win))`

Answer (score 0):

```
(df_1 <- data.frame(
  win=c(1,0,1,1,0,1)
))


library(tidyverse)

df_1 |> mutate(
  cumwin=cumsum(win),
  nrow=row_number(),
  avg_win = cumwin/nrow
)
```

credit to [Mael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13460602/ma%c3%abl)
it could have been more directly

```
df_1 |> mutate(
  avg_win = cummean(win)
)
```